# Why are array elements passed into .then() accessible by name in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, promise, arcgis-js-api, esri-loader

I have started integrating our ArcGis JS template into the webpack build pipeline we are using.

In order to accomplish this, we need to refactor quiet a bit and need to start using the Esri-Loader (https://github.com/Esri/esri-loader), which essentially wraps dojos require function into a promise.

A really simple example looks like this:

```
start = () => {
    return EsriLoader.loadModules(['esri/Map', 'esri/views/MapView', "esri/Basemap"])
        .then(([Map, MapView, Basemap]) => {
            const map = new Map({
                basemap: "streets"
              });

              const view = new MapView({
                map: map,
                container: "map"
              });
        });
}
```

At first I tried writing the call to `.then()` like this: `.then((Map, MapView, Basemap) => { ... }`, but was receiving the following compiler error:

> Argument of type '(Map: any, MapView: any, Basemap: any) => void' is
>   not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any[]) => void |
>   PromiseLike'.

Ok, so the signature does not add up:

```
function loadModules(modules: string[], loadScriptOptions?: ILoadScriptOptions): Promise<any[]>;
```

So the correct way to do this is like above: `.then(([Map, MapView, Basemap]) => { ... }`

And at this point my understanding has reached its limit. In the following method body I am able to call `Map`, `MapView` and `BaseMap` by their name, while I was expecting this to be an array, which I had to be accessing javascript-ish like `Arguments[0][0]`, `Arguments[0][1]` and so on, since I did pass in only one object of type `Array<any>`.

Please explain to me why and how this is possible or if I am doing something horribly wrong here.

Comment: See [Array Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring).

Comment: It does  [destructuring](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#destructuring).

Comment: how come you can pass types into a promise?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon What do you mean? `Map` et al are no types in this context

Comment: > In order to accomplish this, we need to refactor quiet a bit and need to start using the Esri-Loader

Have you seen the new 
 [arcgis webpack plugin](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-webpack-plugin), this may enable you move your existing code into your webpack build pipeline with less refactoring since you can use `import` statements. You might want to give it a try. If it doesn't work for you, you can always fall back to esri-loader.

Comment: No I have not and will def. give it a shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called destructuring.

```
let [a, b, c] = result;
```

it's the same as

```
let a = result[0];
let b = result[1];
let c = result[2];
```

Same goes for function args

```
function ([a,b,c]) {
}
```

it's the same as

```
function (args) {
  let a = args[0];
  let b = args[1];
  let c = args[2];
}
```

You can also do object destructuring:

```
let { a, b, c } = item;
```

same as:

```
let a = item.a;
let b = item.b;
let c = item.c;
```

In your case, the code can be written as:

```
start = () => {
    return EsriLoader.loadModules(['esri/Map', 'esri/views/MapView', "esri/Basemap"])
        .then(modules => {
            const Map = modules[0];
            const MapView = modules[1];
            const Basemap = modules[2];
            const map = new Map({
                basemap: "streets"
              });

              const view = new MapView({
                map: map,
                container: "map"
              });
        });
}
```

Comment: Looks like I definitly need a refresher on all the new ECMA stuff. I feel old. This sums it up nicely for me. Thank you.